# TypeORM "OR" operator only accept nested object query

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

For example I have this Entity

```
export class GenerationEntity{
 @Column()
 generation: string

 @ManyToOne((type) => GenerationEntity, (generationEntity) => generationEntity.nextGen)
 previousGen: string

 @OneToMany((type) => GenerationEntity, (generationEntity) => generationEntity.previousGen)
 nextGen: string
}
```

When I am trying to query it with OR operator without any nested object:

```
await this.generationEntity.findAndCount({
 where: [
  {generation: 'Generation Z'},
  {generation: 'Generation Alpha'}
 ],
 ......
 relations: {previousGen: true, nextGen: true}
})
```

As expected the returned result will be either **Generation Z** OR **Generation Alpha**

However if I do this:

```
await this.generationEntity.findAndCount({
 where: [
  {generation: 'Generation Z'},
  {previousGen: {generation: 'Generation X'}},
 ],
 ......
 relations: {previousGen: true, nextGen: true}
})
```

The returned result will always only be **Generation X** and ignoring the **Generation Z**

I am expecting the query looks at least like this in SQL:

`WHERE generation = 'Generation Z' OR previousGen = 'Generation X'`

I have no clue what went wrong...

Comment: "*I am expecting the query looks at least like this in SQL*" - did you inspect the generated SQL? Does it actually look like that?

Comment: @Bergi 

I believe an array in `where: [{}]` indicates `OR` clause, only object/curly braces `where: {}` indicates `AND` clause. [source](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md)

Comment: @Bergi May I know how do I inspect the generated SQL from TypeORM?

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's indeed an OR not an AND. To inspect the generated SQL, look at the postgres logs or step with a debugger into the typeorm methods.

Comment: Try to include the `relations` as well : `{ where: [...], relations: ["previousGen"] }`

Comment: @W.S. I did include the `relations` in my code as well, will update the example in the post. I think the array syntax `["previousGen"]` will soon be deprecated and `{previousGen: true}` is preferred.

Comment: Ok. Try to share the SQL generated by TypeORM for the specific query as requested above. To log the query, make sure you include `logging: ["query"]` in your datasource/connection options. https://typeorm.io/logging#logging-options

Comment: Sorry for the inactivity past weeks. 
With the `logging: ["query"]` option, I now can see the generated query on the `where` clause.  

`... WHERE (("GenerationEntity__GenerationEntity_previousGen"."generation" = $1) OR ("GenerationEntity"."generation" = $2)) -- PARAMETERS: ["Generation X", "Generation Z"]`.  

The generated query seems fine... but the result will still only return "Generation X" without result for "Generation Z".